# Sitecore null value exception

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, solrnet

I had a Sitecore installation running until I made a deploy with some code changes. After that it completely broke.

Prior to this I create a new template item with a field of type "multilist with search". I didn't generate synthesis code before deploying.

Following is the exception from the IIS.

[image: The exception]

This exception is thrown on *all* pages. This also means that I can't access the content editor. I can't use Sitecore rocks either.

does anybody have any idea on what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For right now, rename `/App_Config/Include/.../Synthesis.config` to `Synthesis.config.disabled`. That should allow you to bring the site back to a state where you can communicate with it.

Be aware that the Multilist with Search field relies on Sitecore ContentSearch - and it appears to be incorrectly configured in your solution.

Comment: I don't know Synthesis well enough to point to the exact configuration file - there could be a couple. Disabling all of them should however, as stated, make the problem go away for right now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you really made my day :-)